# How to turn this into python list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, input, list-comprehension

So basically I am trying to make a list comprehension function that will add to a list called answers if the input is one character and is one of the choices in the choice list[a,b,c,d,e,A,B,C,D,E].

```
def anwser(numQ):
    anwserlist = list()
    choice = [a, b, c, d, e, A, B, C, D, E]
    for num in numQ:
        a = input(prompt)
        if len(a) > 1 and a in choice:
            awnserlist.append(a)
```

this is what i have so far but it doesnt work.

```
anwsers = [a = input(f'What is the anwser to question{num}?')for num in range(1,numQ+1) if len(a) < 2 and in choices]
```

Comment: First, I'd recommend separating your UI from the checking logic (I'm not sure what this app is/does). Secondly, `answer` breaks encapsulation and accesses global scope in the not-shown letter vars `a`, `b`, `c`, etc. These are poorly-named and accessing them from inside a function is unsafe--should they change unexpectedly between calls, you may introduce hard-to-find bugs. Lastly, please provide a [mcve] with runnable code and an explanation for the program spec. Thanks.

Comment: If you simply ignore an invalid input, how will you know which answers correspond to which questions? I would recommend at least appending `None` to the list in the event of an invalid answer. Another option is to read input *until* a valid answer is provided.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the following

```
answerList = [a for num, a in zip(numQ, iter(lambda: input(prompt), None)) if len(a) > 1 and a in choice]
```

but I wouldn't recommend it. Not every loop needs to or should be replaced by a list comprehension, and what you have now is fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
valid_choices = {'a', 'b', 'c','d','e','A', 'B','C','D','E'}
numQ = 3

answers = [a for a in (input(f'What is the anwser to question{num}? ') for num in range(1, numQ+1)) if a in valid_choices]
print(answers)
```